# Is there a way to add descriptive name to applications folder apps?

Tags: macos

I am getting up in years, and have a hard time remembering what each of the many apps in my applications folder do.

Is there a way, or an add-on that I can use to add short descriptive names to the Dock Applications folder contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use OS X. I am a little nervous about renaming applications because there may be links in OS, or the application helpers, that expect a particular name. Therefore, I have gotten into the habit of creating a folder in the Applications folder, with the name I want. Then I move the application into that folder. And with a folder, one can also add supporting files, such as help files, notes, etc.